# Java sound doesn't work on Windows, but work on OS X

Tags: java, javasound

I have problem with playing sounds in my java application. Sound is playing when user get message. Everything is working on OS X but on Windows it doesn't. I put file to jar using this command: jar uf client.jar getMsgSound.wav . I suppose that the problem is with find this file.

```
public String soundName = "getMsgSound.wav";

public void playSound()
{
try {
    File soundFile = new File(soundName);
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the sound actually works in the Windows machine and it isn't muted?

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use `File` to access them. Read about `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: A URL will work within jars. File does not work in within a Jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's on Mac OS, I don't think you can read a file from a jar this way. You might just happen to place the file somewhere in your project and it gets loaded.

I just tested with reading the file directly without putting it into a jar, it worked for both Mac OS and Windows.

So as Greg just pointed out in the comments, you should load it from the jar file using ClassLoader.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/6041964) for how to load resources using ClassLoader.

Comment: You're right. I put on OS X file.wav with my jar, thats why it worked here. On Windows was only a jar file. That worked for me :
public String soundName = "/getMsgSound.wav";
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(soundName);
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);

I add file to jar with maven:

<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>getMsgSound.wav</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

Comment: Yeah, should always use Class Loader to load resource files.